# Incrementing a date in Groovy gets an incorrect date

Tags: groovy

In my Grails project I have a date in the controller and I need to increment this date by **one month**, so I did as below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss");
def temp
use (TimeCategory)
{
    temp=new Date()+30.days//current date 6-1-2016
}
println(sdf.format(temp))
```

this was the output:

```
2016-02-36
```

I tried `plus(30)` also giving me the same result. Is there a way to do this increment correctly?

Comment: It works correctly, are you sure it gives you bad result?

Comment: Which groovy version are you using? How do you display the date?

Comment: groovy version 2.4, i edited the original post

Comment: You should probably add `1.month` instead of `30.days`

Comment: @doelleri, why? It should give the same result. Looks like a bug.

Comment: @Opal Is a month always 30 days?

Comment: @doelleri, of course it's not ;) However, adding `30.days` should also give a valid result.

Comment: i printed the `temp` only i got `Sat Feb 06 21:47:18 EET 2016` , so the problem now is in the `sdf.format()` , but i don't know what may lead me to this output `2016-02-36`

Comment: @doelleri i think you are right , using `1.month` is more accurate as some months have 30 or 31 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Java date format, `D` stands for "Day in Year", hence `6+30 = 36`. You want to use `d` for "Day in month".

You are also using `Y` which is "Week year" instead of `y` which is "year" and `M` for minutes when you want `m`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Opps , i forgot totally to review this , after editing it's working fine .

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this approach :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30)
```

or another approach is to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)